# Can Not Open Google or Google Capthcas

Tags: networking, dns, windows-10

I can't enter "www.google.com" from my desktop on any browser. It always says "Error code 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)".
But I can enter if I write www.google.com.tr (I'm from Turkey) or if I use VPN. Due to this reason, I can't open gmail too.
This also causes google captchas not opening too. Because of that I can't login into some web sites.
This isn't happening on my phone or tablet, they are all normal. So it's not a problem of my modem.
I have tried flushing dns with outher command prompt commands, uninstalling virus protection, turning off windows defender completely, using other dns etc.
I have tried pinging "google.com" and it works. But I can't ping "www.google.com". It again throws timeout error.
I don't want to reset my windows just for this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. If anyone having similar issue, check this out:
My hosts file was containing "216.58.208.164 www.google.com" line. I deleted it and reset my ethernet adapter. After that, I'm able to enter google and open captchas.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried clearing cache and cookies? or closing every tab except the one you are using and uninstalling extensions that aren't needed, maybe it's a memory issue as it is simply timing out

edit: found this from google support that may help
https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0kPkVzx_HQWI/?hl=en

Comment: Should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I have tried many more stuff among cleaning cache. Doesn't work.

Comment: oh yeah my bad, shouldn't have done that, added a link that may help

Comment: These are regular fixes for regular problems I suppose. I have already tried these solutions. Not working.